# Importing data from all workbooks in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I give up. I've searched, I've hunted through SO, I've seen any number of deeply confusing three-page code segments to go through, and frankly while I'm sure they're all good solutions the code is just beyond me.

I have a bunch of data sheets, identical in structure but with lots of different data in them. They're all being stored in the same directory, and I'm trying to make a macro to cycle through them.

This was my original attempt (where `RunImport` is the function that copies over all those data fields). It doesn't work.

```
Private Sub But_BatchRun_Click()
Dim sImpFolder As String, wb As Workbook

sImpFolder = GetFolder

For Each wb In sImpFolder
    call runimport (wb)
Next wb

End Sub
```

Is there any *easy and short* way to do this that doesn't involve eight pages of code?

Comment: Why don't you just use this solution and probe each file for the `.xls` (or any other relevante) extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Comment: what Ralph wrote, its less than 10 lines of code, also don't forget to fix your type error to `Call RunImport (wb)`

Comment: Have you checked Microsoft's VBA material? They do it in 5 lines of code. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139724

Comment: Shai, well spotted - cheers. Ambie, Ralph - thanks, I'll take a look at those links.

Comment: @Ambie, your suggestion is working nicely. Combined with Thomas Inzina's note to open the workbook it all seems to be a go. Would you prefer me to post my finished code with credit to you both or do you want to post it as an answer yourselves?

Comment: Neither, just accept the answer from @ThomasInzina. Are you also aware that there are ways of reading closed workbooks, so you don't have to open each one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783448/reference-a-cell-if-the-sheet-contains-a-certain-string-using-vba/38788689#38788689

Comment: Done, cheers. Will look at that link too - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use a FileSystemObject or a Dir search; you'll still need to open the file.

```
Sub ProcessXLFiles()
    Const FolderPath = "C:\stackoverfow\Sample Data File\*.xl*"
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath)

    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        callrunimport FileName
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```